# What's the equivalent to 'explorer .' (Windows) or 'open .' (Mac)?

Tags: gui, command-line

Inside the terminal, I could use the command 'explorer .' in Win32 or 'open .' in Mac to open GUI explorer/Finder.

What's the equivalent command in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`xdg-open .` will do what you want based on what is set as the default file manager, however since nautilus is the default I personally find it easier to autocomplete `nautilus .`

(Note that xdg-open is supposed to supercede gnome-open, as it's a [Freedesktop.org solution](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/) that is cross-desktop and agreed upon instead of GNOME/KDE specific)

Comment: Interesting.  I have generally used `nautilus --browser` .  I wonder if there is any functional difference with and without the `--browser` argument.

Comment: You might also be interested in `gnome-open .` which will also default to nautilus for a directory.

Comment: If I where to use `sudo`, I'ld use `sudo -- nautilus --no-desktop .` so that a new desktop is not created. If not, the desktop is messed up.

Answer (score 4):

You may wish to give a chance to dolphin, which can be easily installed (if not already) by dropping the next line in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dolphin
```

Dolphin is more like a "Finder" and it features the sliding effect in the vertical columns when opening folders and some other useful features.

After installind (or if already installed) drop the next in a terminal, or [Alt][F2] in order to invoke the "Run application" box in order to enter the next command:

```
dolphin
```

And enjoy.

A screenshot is placed here for you to see dolphin in action.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and how can you have the Mac-like doc in ubunut?

Comment: @ prossekk: http://askubuntu.com/questions/209/what-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-different-docks

Comment: The Dock that I am using (the one in the screenshot) is called "Docky". I personally tested lots of applications, such as: gnome-do, awn and a few other (even the gnome-panel can be set up as a dock itself) but the only which had no problems at all is Docky. Information and "how-to's" can be reached here: http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki

Answer (score 1):

I have installed gvfs-bin to get the `gvfs-open` command and then setup an alias in my `~/.bashrc` for `open` so it works pretty much just like OS X. I can do `open .` to open a nautilus window or `open file` to open a file in the default program for that file.

Answer (score 1):

I use `mimeopen` and it works perfectly fine. Look at it's man page too, it has some handy options.

Answer (score 0):

On gnome (the ubuntu default) it's `gnome-open`

Comment: Please check Jorge answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23596/whats-the-equivalent-to-explorer-windows-or-open-mac/23597#23597

Answer (score 0):

An improvement over [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23597/828709) which gets rid of the noise from stderr and stdout:

```
open () {
        nohup xdg-open $1 > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```