# Is there a way to open a terminal from xdg-open or nautilus?

Tags: command-line

I asked and was answered at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23596/whats-the-equivalent-to-explorer-win32-or-open-mac) about opening a GUI explorer from a command line.

How about the other way around? I mean, is there a way to open a terminal from xdg-open or nautilus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install [nautilus-open-terminal](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-open-terminal) (from Software Center or using `apt-get`) you can right click and open a terminal from wherever you right click:

[image]

You'll need to either log out or restart nautilus with a `nautilus -q` in order for it to take effect after you install it.