# How to Enable or Show Ubuntu or Mac style Dock Bar in Ubuntu?

Tags: dock

I want to know How to Enable/Disable Dock bar in Ubuntu. i.e: How to Disable when we dont need it and how to re-enable it, in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the advantages and disadvantages of different docks?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/209/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-different-docks)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend CairoDock for Ubuntu (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CairoDock). I haven't used it yet, but it seems to be very popular (and customizable). Let me know if this solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

Cairodock. I use it and it is pretty good, it has alot lf customization options, there are a bunch of different  themes created by the community, if you search on the ubuntu app store(or whatever it was called, I dont really use it xD) its there, just install and use it, you might need to add it to the startup if you want it to run as soon as you enter the OS, or you can use the GNOME enviroment :)

Answer (score 0):

Docky is your solution, install it via synaptic or apt-get. It really looks like a Mac doc with simple customization and very light weight too.